# Installing Autodesk maya 2016

Tags: software-installation, 15.10

[image]

I get this error whenever I try to install autodesk maya on ubuntu 15.10. I would appreciate some help.

Comment: It's throwing an RPM error. You might have picked up the installer for Red Hat/Fedora.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert rpm into deb to do that, just copy all the commands below and paste it on your terminal one by one

> sudo apt-get install csh tcsh libaudiofile-dev libglw1-mesa elfutils gamin libglw1-mesa-dev mesa-utils xfstt ttf-liberation ttf-mscorefonts-installer xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi alien
>
> sudo mkdir /usr/tmp
>
> sudo chmod 777 /usr/tmp
>
> sudo alien -cv *.rpm
>
> sudo dpkg -i *.deb
>
> sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so.5.2.0 /usr/autodesk/maya2016/lib/libtiff.so.3
>
> sudo apt-get install libssl1.0.0 libssl-dev
>
> sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 /usr/autodesk/maya2016/lib/libcrypto.so.10
>
> sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 /usr/autodesk/maya2016/lib/libssl.so.10
>
> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/Autodesk/Adlm/R11/lib64/
>
> chmod +x setup
> sudo ./setup

After this you will put your serial number and all, at the end it will still show you error, same error by you have already installed those packages, so it wont matter.

sudo /usr/autodesk/maya2016/bin/maya

and at the end
I'm stuck at this error
"/usr/autodesk/maya2016/bin/maya.bin: error while loading shared libraries: libtiff.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Its a dependency error and i am trying to solve this one, no luck so far.
if you find can go further, don't forget to post here :)

Comment: So, this answer you posted doesn't work?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/786380/autodesk-maya-2016-not-openning-due-to-libtiff-so-3-dependecy-error-help


Check the solution of the above link. For the rest of the solution :)