# Autodesk Maya 2016 not openning due to libtiff.so.3 dependecy error

Tags: software-installation, 16.04

While installing Autodesk Maya, I'm stuck at this error

```
"/usr/autodesk/maya2016/bin/maya.bin: error while loading shared libraries: libtiff.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"
```

If anyone has any idea about how to solve this one, please help :)

I am using x64 bit PC